# Adding VMs To Azure Virtual Network

Tags: azure, networking, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I am new to Azure and any trying to create a Virtual Network with 2 VM's in it. I have created the Virtual Network (VN) OK (see attached screenshot) and can also create the VMs but the Vis do not show up as resources on the VN and I cannot see where to sin them when creating the VM. I suspect its to do with subnets etc and IPs but I am now to this and cannot figure it out. See the screenshots attached showing the VM and the VN Resource list

I am using Azure Classic Portal as I need to set up Domain Services on my VN and am using the Select From Gallery option when creating my VMS.

Comment: no screenshot attached

Answer (score 0):

When you create VMs from Gallery you should select `Region/Virtual network` as the following screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Also, if you want to move existing VM to Virtual Network, you could refer to this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/karldb/2013/12/13/moving-an-existing-virtual-machine-into-a-virtual-network-subnet-without-losing-your-virtual-hard-disk-or-your-mind/).